# How to handle IllegalStateException in file transfer using Smack library?

Tags: java, android, chat, smack, illegalstateexception

i am making an chat application using asmack-jse-buddycloud-2010 library.By using this i am able to do chat and file transfer but in testing 1 scenario occur's , while transferring file(suppose file size > 1MBs or anysize) either server goes down or we loose internet connection in that case application get crashes by throwing  an exception

**Error Log:**

```
  07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913): FATAL EXCEPTION: File Transfer jsi_555743874184501198
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913): Process: com.example.chat_demo, PID: 12913
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not connected to server.
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smack.XMPPConnection.sendPacket(XMPPConnection.java:488)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.SyncPacketSend.getReply(SyncPacketSend.java:41)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.SyncPacketSend.getReply(SyncPacketSend.java:61)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession$IQIBBOutputStream.writeToXML(InBandBytestreamSession.java:763)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession$IBBOutputStream.flushBuffer(InBandBytestreamSession.java:707)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession$IBBOutputStream.closeInternal(InBandBytestreamSession.java:737)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession.closeByLocal(InBandBytestreamSession.java:191)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession.close(InBandBytestreamSession.java:153)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession$IQIBBOutputStream.writeToXML(InBandBytestreamSession.java:768)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession$IBBOutputStream.flushBuffer(InBandBytestreamSession.java:707)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession$IBBOutputStream.writeOut(InBandBytestreamSession.java:679)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession$IBBOutputStream.write(InBandBytestreamSession.java:641)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamSession$IBBOutputStream.write(InBandBytestreamSession.java:644)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransfer.writeToStream(FileTransfer.java:217)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.OutgoingFileTransfer$2.run(OutgoingFileTransfer.java:231)
07-02 13:09:05.983: E/AndroidRuntime(12913):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:811)
```

i tried to catch this exception but still application crash with same exception
any help will be appreciated.

**here is my code**

```
    File file ;

    configureProviderManager(connection);

    FileTransferNegotiator.setServiceEnabled(connection, true);
    FileTransferManager manager = new FileTransferManager(connection);




String to = connection.getRoster().getPresence(to).getFrom();


                         transfer = manager.createOutgoingFileTransfer(to);

                 try {

                            configureProviderManager(connection);
            //here file trasfer occur's .parameters are file and filename(has nothing to do with transfer)

                           transfer.sendFile(file,file.getName().tostring());

                    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                            Log.i("illegal state exception","caught  ");
                            //transfer.cancel();
                        }catch (XMPPException e) {

                               e.printStackTrace();
                               }

                 while(!transfer.isDone()) {
                            if (transfer.getStatus() == Status.error) {

                                    transfer.cancel();
                            }


                            if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.refused))
                            System.out.println("refused  " + transfer.getError());
                            else if( transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.error))

                                 System.out.println(" error " + transfer.getError());
                                 } 
                            if(transfer.getStatus().equals(Status.cancelled)){

                             System.out.println(" cancelled  " + transfer.getError());
                             }

                            else


                            System.out.println("Success");

                            }


                        }

    }
```

Comment: Can  you please provide full stack trace? And also the code line where exception occurs.

Comment: @Sanjeev please check post now..i edited "error log" ... exception occure due to connection closed while transfer line:"transfer.sendFile(file, ""+file.getName());"

Comment: What does variable `transfer` holds?

Comment: it is an object of "OutgoingFileTransfer transfer;"

Comment: Can you please provide full code?

Comment: only this much code is required for sending a file ..rest is about creating connection..[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9784320/cannot-send-message-to-openfire-server

Answer (score 0):

try checking the status of your XMPPConnection before sending the file:

```
if(connection.isConnected()){
     transfer.sendFile(file,file.getName().tostring());
} else {
     // message to the user
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. but try to visualize the scenario .. let suppose connection was there and this function sendFile() got executed and process went into the thread. now file size is in MB's so it take time to transfer, mean while connection get lost now in library(XAMPPConnection.java) there is function called SendPacket() in which it checks connection like if(!isConnected){ throw new illegalestate exception}. hope you dig more to visualize problem.. check log trace

Comment: Yeah i digged till that place and you can not do much about that kind of scenario yourself. you need to ask help from smack creators.